# Validation create user in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to create user by restful Api , but i have a error to validation create user  :

```
BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 283:
Method [throwValidationException] does not exist.
```

My validation code and create user in AuthController.php is:

```
 protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        'phone' => 'required|numeric',
        'mobile' => 'required|confirmed|min:11|max:11|numeric',
        'address' => 'required|min:6',
        'state' => 'required',
        'city' => 'required',
        'post_code' => 'required|numeric|min:10|max:10'
    ]);
}
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'phone' => $data['phone'],
        'mobile' => $data['mobile'],
        'address' => $data['address'],
        'state' => $data['state'],
        'city' => $data['city'],
        'post_code' => $data['post_code'],
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add **ValidatesRequests** traits to your controller. This is the piece of code that provides **throwValidationException** method that **RegistersUsers** trait uses.